# How to transform a multi dimensional array from a CSV file into a list

Tags: python, arrays, csv, dataset

[screenshot of the csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cL4ji.png)

Hi(sorry if this is a dump question)..i have a data set as CSV file ...every row contains 44 column and every cell containes 44 float number separated by two spaces like this(look at the screenshot) ...i tried CSV readline/s +  numpy  and non of them worked
i want to take every row as a list with[1936] variable (44*44)
and then combine the whole data set into 2d array ...my_data[n_of_samples][1936]

Comment: This is not a standard CSV and has few issues that you will need to take care of before parsing to make your life easier. The first thing you should try is to clean up the file so that each row is in a single line so that you can parse it one line at a time.

Comment: @ybl can you suggest anyway to do that ? :)

Comment: I know this can be done using `vim`, but I am not sure how adept are you with it. Otherwise, you can just use python to convert it to something that `numpy` understands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so as stated by user ybl, this is not a CSV. It's not even close to being a CSV.

This means that you have to implement some processing to turn this into something useable. I put the screenshot through an OCR to extract the actual text values, but next time provide the input file. Screenshots of data are annoying to work with.

The processing you need to to is to find the start and end of the rows, using the `[` and `]` characters respectively. Then you split this data with the basic `string.split()` which doesn't care about the number of spaces.

Try the code below and see if that works for the input file.

```py
rows = []
current_row = ""


with open("somefile.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile.readlines():
        cleaned = line.replace('"', '').replace("\n", " ")
        if "]" in cleaned:
            current_row = f"{current_row} {cleaned.split(']')[0]}"
            rows.append(current_row.split())
            current_row = ""
            cleaned = cleaned.split(']')[1]
        if "[" in cleaned:
            cleaned = cleaned.split("[")[1]
        current_row = f"{current_row} {cleaned}"


for row in rows:
    print(len(row))
```

**output**

```
44
44
44
```

**input file:**

```
"[ 1.79619717e+04    1.09988207e+02     4.13270009e+01    1.72227906e+01
   1.06178751e+01    5.20957856e+00     7.50891645e+00    4.57943370e+00
   2.65572713e+00    2.96725867e-01     2.43040664e+00    1.32822091e+00
   4.09853169e-01    1.18412873e+00     6.43398990e-01    1.23796528e+00
   9.63975374e-02    2.95295579e-01     7.68998970e-01    4.98040980e-01
   2.84036936e-01    1.76004564e-01     1.43527613e-01    1.64765236e-01
   1.51171075e-01    1.02586637e-01     3.27835810e-02    1.21872869e-02
   -7.59824907e-02   8.48217334e-02     7.29953754e-02    4.89750588e-02
   5.89426950e-02    5.05485266e-02     2.34761263e-02    -2.41095452e-02
   5.15952510e-02    1.39933210e-02     2.12354074e-02    3.40820680e-03
   -2.57466949e-03   -1.06481222e-02    -8.35155410e-03   1.21653512e-12]","[-6.12189619e+02       1.03584744e+04     2.34417495e+02     7.01761526e+01
   3.92495170e+01    1.81609738e+01     2.58114624e+01    1.52275550e+01
   8.59676934e+00    9.45036161e-01     7.71943506e+00    4.17516432e+00
   1.27920413e+00    3.68862368e+00     1.99582544e+00    3.82999035e+00
   2.96068511e-01    9.06341796e-01     2.35621065e+00    1.52094079e+00
   8.64565916e-01    5.34605108e-01     4.35456793e-01    4.99450615e-01
   4.57778770e-01    3.10324997e-01     9.90860520e-02    3.68281889e-02
   -2.29532895e-01   2.56108491e-01     2.20284123e-01    1.47727878e-01
   1.77724506e-01    1.52350751e-01     7.07318164e-02    -7.26252404e-02
   1.55364050e-01    4.21222079e-02     6.39113311e-02    1.02558665e-02
   -7.74736016e-03   -3.20368093e-02    -2.51241082e-02   1.21653512e-12]","[-5.03959282e+02       -5.64452044e+02    7.90433958e+03     1.94146598e+02
   1.06178751e+01    5.20957856e+00     7.50891645e+00    4.57943370e+00
   2.65572713e+00    2.96725867e-01     2.43040664e+00    1.32822091e+00
   4.09853169e-01    1.18412873e+00     6.43398990e-01    1.23796528e+00
   9.63975374e-02    2.95295579e-01     7.68998970e-01    4.98040980e-01
   2.84036936e-01    1.76004564e-01     1.43527613e-01    1.64765236e-01
   1.51171075e-01    1.02586637e-01     3.27835810e-02    1.21872869e-02
   -7.59824907e-02   8.48217334e-02     7.29953754e-02    4.89750588e-02
   5.89426950e-02    5.05485266e-02     2.34761263e-02    -2.41095452e-02
   5.15952510e-02    1.39933210e-02     2.12354074e-02    3.40820680e-03
   -2.57466949e-03   -1.06481222e-02    -8.35155410e-03   1.21653512e-12]"
```

Comment: thanx a lot + sorry for the screenshot thing XD

Answer (score 0):

The option is this:

```
import numpy as np
import csv


c = np.array([n_of_samples])

with open('cocacola_sick.csv') as f:
    p = csv.reader(f)  # read file as csv
    for s in p:
        a = ','.join(s)  # concatenate all lines into one line
        a = a.replace("\n", "")  # remove line breaks
b = np.array(np.mat(a))
my_data = np.vstack((c,b))
print(my_data)
```

Comment: i got an error implementing it ..ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 1 and the array at index 1 has size 0 
+ thanx for ur answer tho :)